# Order and get element by timestamp using cloud Firestore and Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jo32.png)

I have a database that I access through Cloud Firestore. It works fine so far if I address the link hard. However, for some information, I want to sort the collection of the database after the timestamp and write out the latest event, in my case the latest temperature.

In the figure, which can be seen under the link, my desired result would be the temperature 19 (546787867678asd8 and timestamp: 5 March 2019 at 18:23:30 UTC+1)

I had already tried different solutions, but none had led to the desired result. Unfortunately, I don't know why. You can find the latest code below

```js
function getLastData() {
    return admin.firestore().collection('temperatur').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').limit(1).get().then(querySnapshot => {
        if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
            const queryDocumentSnapshot = querySnapshot.docs[0].temp;
            console.log('The temperature is ', queryDocumentSnapshot);
            return queryDocumentSnapshot;
        } else {
            console.log('No document');
            return null;
        }
    });}

console.log(getLastData());
```

I would expect something like the following: 
The temperature is 23
However, the result is:
The temperature is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[By docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.html), you have to extract it using `.data()` or `.get(<prop>)`:

```
function getLastData() {
    return admin.firestore().collection('temperatur').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').limit(1).get().then(querySnapshot => {
        if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
            const queryDocumentSnapshot = querySnapshot.docs[0].get('temp');
            console.log('The temperature is ', queryDocumentSnapshot);
            return queryDocumentSnapshot;
        } else {
            console.log('No document');
            return null;
        }
    });}

console.log(getLastData());
```

Comment: Many many thanks! Thank you very much. Your hint has solved the problem :)